# WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync doesn't work without await

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

I have simple wpf application with one button and one textblock. Button click event handler run next code:

```
var resultTask = webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com");
textBlock.Text = resultTask.Result;
```

And this doesn't work (it hangout) until I use await

```
var result = await ebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com");
textBlock.Text = result;
```

But in simple console application it work fine.

```
var resultTask = webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com");
Console.WriteLine(resultTask.Result);
```

Can you explane me why first variant doesn't work in wpf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a commonly seen issue with sync-contexts; basically, the `.Result` can't get the sync-context until the UI thread is available, and the UI thread will not be available until `.Result` completes (or fails). Basically, you have deadlocked yourself, which is why you shouldn't use `.Wait()` or `.Result` unless you know the sync-context is safe - just `await`.

It works in a console app because there is no sync-context: the continuation can be marked complete on a pool thread.  In WPF, the sync-context pushes work to the UI thread, which is can't do because of the deadlock.

A hacky fix would be to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` after the `*Async` method:

```
var resultTask = webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://google.com")
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But this works for all the wrong reasons and should be avoided. Either use `await`, or use a synchronous call. Don't do "sync over async" - it is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're deadlocking on the UI event thread. The accepted answer on the question below explains it in more detail:

[Deadlock while blocking async HttpClient call within a task continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825467/deadlock-while-blocking-async-httpclient-call-within-a-task-continuation)